# Does an alchemist need make a Spellcraft check when he wants to copy a formula?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

An alchemist can add formulae to his book just like a wizard adds spells to his spellbook, using the same costs and time requirements.

But it's not mentioned same "Spellcraft check" so I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alchemists aren't mentioned in the Spellcraft skill simply because the Alchemist wasn't around when the Core rules were written and it's never been updated.

The only key difference between a wizard learning and an alchemist is that [alchemists do not need to decipher arcane writings before copying them](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Alchemy-Su-).

Therefore, to copy a spell/formula to your formula book:

1. Get a spell/scroll/formula book with a formula that an alchemist can use.
2. If you were a Wizard you'd have to [Understand the text](http://paizo.com/prd/magic.html#adding-spells-to-a-wizard-s-spellbook#arcane-magical-writings) DC 20 + the spell's level. Failure means trying again the next day. But alchemists don't need to do this.
3. Study the formula for an hour.
4. [Understand the formula](http://paizo.com/prd/magic.html#adding-spells-to-a-wizard-s-spellbook) DC 15 + the formula/spell's level. Failure means try again in a week.
5. Copy the formula into your own book. This takes 1 hour per formula level (0 = <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> hour) This takes 1 page/level and costs money to pay for materials (see below)
6. If this was on a scroll then that scroll is used up and useless.

Note that you [can take 10](http://paizo.com/prd/usingSkills.html#taking-10-and-taking-20) on these checks if "your character is not in immediate danger or distracted".

```
Lvl Cost
0   5 gp
1   10 gp
2   40 gp
3   90 gp
4   160 gp
5   250 gp
6   360 gp
7   490 gp
8   640 gp
9   810 gp
```

Being a Wizard or an alchemist is expensive.

Comment: Do you have an official source indicating that the Alchemist was meant to follow these rules, or is this your personal speculation?

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop It's right in the linked description of the alchemist.  "An alchemist can also add formulae to his book just like a wizard adds spells to his spellbook, using the same costs and time requirements"  and " An alchemist does not need to decipher arcane writings before copying them."

Comment: @starwed I guess my confusion was about the first sentence. This answer indicates that the answer isn't in the alchemist rules, and gives an explanation as to why.
In any case, step #4 above doesn't seem like it needs to be part of "costs and time requirements", so I was hoping for an official mention of that somewhere.

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop I read the "cost and time" clause as a clarification, not a restriction.  Especially given the later, more explicit statement about deciphering.

Comment: I see. I personally still think the first sentence is confusing, but I'm not sure what @Rob wanted to say, so I won't suggest an edit for that.

Comment: I'll clarify my waffle